# Drive cycle for 2007 Nissan Sentra

Tags: nissan, sentra, drive-cycle

I have a 2007 Nissan Sentra 2L and have the codes reader.  I had reset the codes in May and driven a bit of variety local and highway (but not all that much due to covid and  traveling).  No codes anymore but one of the O2 codes says "Not Ready"

Is there an official (-ish?) *Drive Cycle* procedure to follow so we can get past that "Not Ready" ? This is for California Smog emissions.

Either a document (which may not exist) or some experience from other owners of this or very similar vehicles would be helpful.

Comment: BTW ... Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this input](https://www.fixya.com/cars/t26303275-drive_cycle_2003_nissan_sentra_se), you should do the following:

> Take extra caution while performing drive cycles on public roadways. Drive cycles can be difficult to follow under normal driving conditions.
> Begin by:
>
> - Start the engine. Idle the engine in drive for two and a half minutes with the A/C and rear defroster on.
> - Turn the A/C and rear defrost off, and accelerate to 55 mph at half throttle.
> - Hold at a steady speed of 55 mph for three minutes.
> - Decelerate (coast down) to 20 mph without braking or depressing the clutch.
> - Accelerate back to 55 to 60 mph at ¾ throttle.
> - Hold at a steady speed of 55 to 60 mph for five minutes.
> - Decelerate (coast down) to a stop without braking.

> If all other emissions systems are functioning properly, completing the drive cycle above will set the "readiness flags" required to pass the smog check. It will not hurt to perform the drive cycle 2 or 3 times before the smog test.

One other thing which matters, though I believe it is for the EVAP system, is to ensure the gas tank is between 25% and 75%. If above or below, it will not complete the drive cycle. Also, in almost all drive cycle cases I've seen, you need to start this with the engine cold.

Comment: This follows closely to what a Nissan dealership service rep of 25 years recommended . He said to repeat the cycle a number of times

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - Drive cycles can be a huge PITB. Hopefully this will work to get your O2 sensors straight, though I would think the O2 sensors would be the first to complete.

Comment: Epilogue: the drive cycle never switched over. I have since moved to WA and cars 2009 and older do not need to pass emissions here. I paid to have the car shipped here.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - Seems some states still have some sanity ... at least in the area of emissions :o)